# Setting a submit value for a form button not working. JS

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to set the type value for a form button, but its not working.

```
let saveBtn = document.createElement("button")
    saveBtn.innerHTML = "Save"
    saveBtn.className = "btn"
    saveBtn.setAttribute('type',"submit")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and it seems ok after appending

```
document.body.appendChild(saveBtn)

<button class="btn" type="submit">Save</button>
```

Comment: thank you! its working now. I just tried to append it to the body to be sure its working and tried again to append it to another element then it start to work. weird!